Message filter subscribe with best effor QoS can't receive message from publisher with reliable QoS
I'm using the pointcloud_to_laserscan package to convert pointcloud from depth camera to laserscan, but the pointcloud_to_laserscan node can't receive message from depth camera.
The QoS for the publisher and subscriber
$ ros2 topic info /depth_camera/points --verbose
Type: sensor_msgs/msg/PointCloud2

Publisher count: 1

Node name: depth_camera_controller
Node namespace: /
Topic type: sensor_msgs/msg/PointCloud2
Endpoint type: PUBLISHER
GID: 01.10.67.02.3d.1b.0b.ff.83.7a.6b.10.00.00.3a.03.00.00.00.00.00.00.00.00
QoS profile:
  Reliability: RELIABLE
  History (Depth): KEEP_LAST (1)
  Durability: VOLATILE
  Lifespan: Infinite
  Deadline: Infinite
  Liveliness: AUTOMATIC
  Liveliness lease duration: Infinite

Subscription count: 1

Node name: pointcloud_to_laserscan
Node namespace: /
Topic type: sensor_msgs/msg/PointCloud2
Endpoint type: SUBSCRIPTION
GID: 01.10.0f.28.f4.6c.9d.a2.f0.05.33.dd.00.00.1c.04.00.00.00.00.00.00.00.00
QoS profile:
  Reliability: BEST_EFFORT
  History (Depth): KEEP_LAST (12)
  Durability: VOLATILE
  Lifespan: Infinite
  Deadline: Infinite
  Liveliness: AUTOMATIC
  Liveliness lease duration: Infinite

From the ROS official document, the QoS should be compatible, but I don't know why there is no message received by the pointcloud_to_laserscan node. So I clone the package and change the subscriber's QoS to reliable, after this change, the pointcloud_to_lasercan node can receive the message. Could someone provide an explaination here? Thanks.

if (subscription_count > 0)
      {
            if (!sub_.getSubscriber())
            {
                RCLCPP_INFO(this->get_logger(),
                            "Got a subscriber to laserscan, starting pointcloud subscriber");
                rclcpp::SensorDataQoS qos;
                qos.keep_last(input_queue_size_);
                qos.reliable(); //change to reliable
                sub_.subscribe(this, "cloud_in", qos.get_rmw_qos_profile());
            }
        }

